# How to generate a UUID in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create a code snippet or a task runner (or anything else) that would allow me to generate a UUID in VSCode? This question can also be interpreted in a more generic way: Can I run an external tool/program and insert the result at the current cursor position.

Thanks.

Comment: This github project may be of interest to you: https://github.com/michaelmcdaniel/GuidgenConsole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do it right now with snippets. I don't think it can work via tasks either.

The only thing I can do for you is to give you a hacky solution that works for C#, TypeScript and Yaml files (tested in VSCode 0.9.0).
Let's implement it for TypeScripts to make an example:

- Go to the folder where VSCode is installed
- Open the file `resources\app\extensions\typescript\out\features\suggestSupport.js`
- Add a method `newGuid()` to the `SuggestSupport` class:

  ```
  // copied from: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/Util.ts
  SuggestSupport.prototype.newGuid = function() {
      var hexValues = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

      // c.f. rfc4122 (UUID version 4 = xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
      var oct = "", tmp;
      for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
          tmp = (4294967296 * Math.random()) | 0;
          oct += hexValues[tmp & 0xF] + hexValues[tmp >> 4 & 0xF] + hexValues[tmp >> 8 & 0xF] + hexValues[tmp >> 12 & 0xF] + hexValues[tmp >> 16 & 0xF] + hexValues[tmp >> 20 & 0xF] + hexValues[tmp >> 24 & 0xF] + hexValues[tmp >> 28 & 0xF];
      }

      // "Set the two most significant bits (bits 6 and 7) of the clock_seq_hi_and_reserved to zero and one, respectively"
      var clockSequenceHi = hexValues[8 + (Math.random() * 4) | 0];
      return oct.substr(0, 8) + "-" + oct.substr(9, 4) + "-4" + oct.substr(13, 3) + "-" + clockSequenceHi + oct.substr(16, 3) + "-" + oct.substr(19, 12);
  }
  ```
- Find the line `var suggests = [];` [inside the `suggest` function]
- Add this suggestion below that line:

  ```
          suggests.push({
              label: "Create new UUID",
              codeSnippet: "\"" + _this.newGuid() + "\"",
              type: "keyword"
          });
  ```

After restarting Code you will always receive in `.ts` files a suggestion called "Create new UUID" which adds a value like `"243BC2A6-1AB5-445B-B086-DBDED67368F5"` at the current cursor position. You can force the appearance of the suggestion box by pressing `CTRL + Space`.

To add this suggestion to C# and YAML you need to do the same in the corresponding suggestSupport.js files.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good approach given how snippets and tasks work in VSCode. I'm trying to get it to work in a json file, I'll let you know if that works too.

Comment: @GabePerez were you able to get into json file as it to be generated when the snippet is used ?

Answer (score 6):

The following extension is super easy to use and does exactly what you want: https://github.com/heaths/vscode-guid (or get it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=heaths.vscode-guid) from the VS Marketplace)

Comment: For those coming to this answer later, if the extension no longer exists just search on the Extensions panel for "GUID" and you'll find a few there.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding code sniper and uuid, consider that VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021) introduces an interesting feature:

> ### [New Snippet Variables](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/461f124c259b722b93cb2b2f83d5e1bd84182776/release-notes/v1_53.md#editor)

> There are new snippet variables for inserting uuids and for inserting the relative path the current file.
>
> The sample snippet below would print:
>
> ```
> let someId = 'foo/test.js/c13d226f-1932-40e2-9fd9-10198c219e33'
> ```
>
> ```yaml
> // sample snippet using UUID and RELATIVE_FILEPATH
> {
>  "scope": "javascript",
>  "prefix": "newVars",
>  "body": "let someId = '${RELATIVE_FILEPATH}/${UUID}'$0"
> }
> ```